# ArrayList is empty but why?

Tags: java, enums, arraylist

I'm trying to add Cards to ArrayList deck, but it doesn't seem to work(most of the code is an example on oracle.com ). I'm probably doing something really stupid, but I can't seem to find it.. this is the code:

```
public class Card {

    public enum Rank 
    {
        DEUCE, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE,
        TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
    }

    public enum Suit
    {
        HEARTS, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS
    }

    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;
    private static final List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    public Card(Rank rank, Suit suit)
    {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    // initializes deck
    public void initDeck()
    {
        for (Suit suit : Suit.values())
        {
            for (Rank rank : Rank.values())
            {
                deck.add(new Card(rank, suit));
            }
        }
    }
    // returns a copy of the deck    
    public static ArrayList<Card> newDeck()
    {
        return new ArrayList<Card>(deck);
    }

    public Rank getRank()
    {
        return rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return rank +" of "+ suit;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(deck.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Obvious check... where do you call `initDeck`?

Comment: lol I wasn't calling initDeck at all haha thanks.

Comment: well, too bad my comment wasn't an answer! Ha!

Comment: You code will still be quite bad even if you call initDeck() :) Read the comments bellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you never actually invoke initDeck, so the deck remains empty, as it was when the static initializer ran:

```
private static final List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
```

Other problems:

1. `initDeck()` is an instance method, but `deck` is a static reference.
2. `initDeck()` is a method on Card.
3. `deck` is a static member of `Card`, but a card does not own or define a deck.
4. `newDeck` is nonsensical in the face of a static final deck.
5. Cards should not be delivering decks anyway.

In short, your design is messed up - you need to think more and harder about the entities and their inter-relationships.

Comment: +1 - the real problem here is that the design is a conceptual mess.

Comment: So I should make a Deck class? And doing this initializing in there?

Answer (score 1):

it is very suspicious that your `deck` is `private static final` and your init method `public` and `non-static`. It can be initialized several times and contain more cards then you would expect. You may want to do the initialization in static block instead.

I would replace the code as follows:

1. make the deck `public static final` and unmodifiable (via Collections)
2. copy the body of your init method in static initializer like this:

> ```
> static {
>   for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
>     for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
>       deck.add(new Card(rank, suit));
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

1. delete `initDeck` completely

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, in your `main` method, you're just `toString()` an empty `ArrayList`. You haven't called `initDeck()` method in your `main` method at all.

When you ran your program `private static final List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();`
, deck was assigned an empty `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `initDeck()` isn't called anywhere. Try to replace `public void initDeck()` with `static`.

Answer (score -2):

The keyword `final` in you `List<card>` definition is for object that will have an starting value that cannot be changed.

Check it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29)

Comment: final doesn't prevent adding/removing elements, only reassigning the reference.

Comment: No, it just means you can't reassign the reference - you can certainly make changes to the object to which it refers.